# Group finder for harder quests?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

I'm a veteran SWTOR player and i casually play LoTRO.
In LoTRO i have reached level 20 now and i am at *"The Great Barrows"*.
These quests (about 5) that are inside this area are to hard to solo and i need a group.

Is there anything like SWTOR has to find a group for a specific quest?

I know there is an instance menu, but when i go there i just get a notification with *Travel now - Travel later - Cancel*

Is this because there are no people online for this specific quest or because the menu i am in isn't really a group finder?

Comment: in which server are you playing?

Comment: Evernight [EU] only lvl 20 tho

Comment: i started playing lotro in a EU server but quickly changed for a US server. much more people,  easier to find fellows at the same lvl to run hard quests/intances, much more fun

Comment: US servers give me to much lag but thx for the suggestion, don't think i'll run a lot of group content tho. i'm to casual.

Comment: Are you in a kinship Vahx?

Comment: no i'm not, not sure what advantages this gives me.

Comment: @Vahx a kinship is like a clan. there you can have have advanteges like: high level palyers will help you on your hardest quests, arrange some instances to run, give you materials that you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a instance finder:

[image],

but its not very popular. Normally, people use the instance finder when they already have a full fellowship and want to get more medallions, marks.

If you wanna get a fellowship to run GB the best way is to spam in global chat or in Bree's channel.